# Quitar espacio entre LinearLayout y sus hijos

Tags: java, android

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ea1a1a"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button

            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <Button
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <Button
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Este es el resultado que se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
.

Lo que necesito es quitar el espacio de arriba y abajo que hay entre el LinearLayout y los Buttons, alguna manera sencilla de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Comment: llegó el típico resentido social

Comment: Sólo intento que aprendas a usar las etiquetas de forma correcta y útil, aunque para alguien que escribe "nobato" no está mal del todo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes modificar el `margin` de los botones:

...

```
android:layout-marginTop="-5sp"
android:layout-marginBottom="-5sp"
```

...

También puedes cambiar el `background` y poner un `shadow` propio.

Comment: No funciona,en la primera opción el boton se desliza un poco hacia arriba y abajo deja un espacio mayor, en la segunda opción solo agranda el boton, no hay forma de quitar ese espacio de otra manera?

Comment: Pues entonces tendrás que probar a hacerle un background propio en lugar del que viene por defecto, y se lo pones con la propiedad background

Comment: y como se hace eso :( soy nobato

Comment: Corrección, si funciona la primera opción que me diste, muchas gracias!